# Trying to pass char index to DrawText

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using `DrawText` to draw some text to a bunch of rectangles I made in a plug-in.

Now i'm receiving a char pointer from embedded python:

```
char *a=PyString_AsString(value);
```

which, when I print to textfile gives: `1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n`
(this is just a sample character, the one I'm going to use is much more complex)

I want to use `DrawText` to print specific characters in a loop:

```
 for(int count=0;count<content.size();count++){
    dc->DrawText(a[count*2],&rect[count],DT_CENTER); //*2 to print only the numbers
```

but i can't because it says that argument is not of type char?? I can pass `a`, `&a[count]` but not `a[count]`. Why is this?

Also, when i print `&a[2]`to textfile it gives: `2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n`. Shouldn't it be only `2`?

Note: [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function receives:

```
int DrawText(
   _In_     HDC hDC,
   _Inout_  LPCTSTR lpchText,
   _In_     int nCount,
   _Inout_  LPRECT lpRect,
   _In_     UINT uFormat
 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of your `DrawText` method is a `char*` pointer. You are passing a single `char` instead, which is the type mismatch that the compiler is complaining about.

You can obtain a pointer to a specific character like this:

```
&a[count*2]
```

or like this:

```
a + count*2
```

The problem is that your three parameter OOP wrapper of `DrawText` has removed the `nCount` parameter of the Win32 `DrawText` function. Instead your wrapper is passing `-1` which means that the character pointer is interpreted as a null-terminated string. The function will print all the characters until it reaches the null-terminator.

If you want to print a single character then you would need to pass `1` through the `nCount` parameter. There's no way for you to do that with your wrapper. You'd have to do this:

```
char temp[2];
temp[1] = 0;
temp[0] = a[count*2];
dc->DrawText(temp, ...);
```

In order to avoid this temporary buffer you would need to expose the `nCount` parameter of the raw Win32 API function.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I forgot about `nCount`. Doing this solves the problem `dc->DrawText(a+count*2,1,&content[count],DT_CENTER);`

However, printing to file  `a+2` for example, gives `2\n3\n4\n...9\n`.Can you explain me why?

Comment: I don't have all the details that you have. So I cannot see your code and cannot comment on unseen code with fragments exposed in comments. I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: yeah,of course you did. I've just marked it as answered. I was just trying to get more information because printing that when asking for `a+2` is not normal behavior right?

Comment: Well, I cannot see your code. I don't know what it is doing. You said you are printing to file.

Comment: yeah, printing to textfile like this: `textfile4<<"a+2 "<<a+2<<endl;`. textfile is a simple ofstream

Comment: That's easy enough. `a+2` is `char*`, pointer to null terminated string. To output a character use `a[2]`.